# Need To Link OData Service with other OData Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, odata, wcf-data-services

I have this scenario. I have two servers and one client DB server :

1. server 1
2. server 2
3. client server

client server can only see server 2 and server 2 can only see server 1 and server 1 can only see DB Server

Client server need to connect to odata service that inside server1 so I need to create new odata inside server 2 read from odata from server1

```
public class WcfDataService1 : DataService<Remote odata >
{
   public static void InitializeService(IDataServiceConfiguration config)
   {
      config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
   }
}
```

what is the easiest way to implement this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You may setup a proxy on server 2. The proxy accepts the requests from the client server and forwards them to server 1.

If you are using IIS, you can reference this:
https://serverfault.com/questions/47537/can-iis-be-configure-to-forward-request-to-another-web-server